What's a term for someone who selectively gets women's names wrong?
For example, calling someone named Denise, Deborah and other women by wrong names, but not with men's names.
Searched google and other word usage sites and didn't find much other than it could be considered a microaggression.
AI suggests "pseudogyny", which sounds plausible, but doesn't appear to be in common usage.
If there is a term or terms, would be interested if intent is differentiated (doing so on purpose vs. unconsciously).

Calling someone by the wrong name belittles them. I offer, from Cambridge Dictionary

negging
the practice of making negative or slightly insulting comments to someone you find attractive in order to make them take an interest in you

